Format of .log file in Kubernetes and how log parsed by Filebeat
Application produces logs to docker container stdout:

{"message": "gateway 200 <== assistant PATCH /admin/info-banners/1/",
"service_name": "НКЗ API Gateway", "level": "INFO", "timestamp":
"2024-04-16T09:27:08.514573", "logger": "app.adapters.base_adapter",
"filepath": "/api_gateway/app/adapters/base_adapter.py", "func":
"_request_service"}

The log then transferred by Kubernetes to .log file and there it looks like this:

2024-04-16T12:27:08.515010847+03:00 stdout F {"message": "gateway 200
<== assistant PATCH /admin/info-banners/1/", "service_name": "НКЗ API
Gateway", "level": "INFO", "timestamp": "2024-04-16T09:27:08.514573",
"logger": "app.adapters.base_adapter", "filepath":
"/api_gateway/app/adapters/base_adapter.py", "func":
"_request_service"}

Question 1: what is stdout? the place where it was taken from?
Question 2: what if F?
Logs in files .log then consumed by filebeat.
Question 3: how filebeat decides how to parse 2024-04-16T12:27:08.515010847+03:00, stdout, F? I mean there types (datetime, string, string). And how filebeat decides to parse a json?

Where is filebeat here?  Does filebeat produce the first output?

Filebeat parses .log files. But here it doesn't matter where filbeat is

Another related answer here. The Kubernetes log is basically in CRI log format.

Means stdout log.
F means a 'full log entry' See here. The other option is P for 'partial'
Your filebeat preprocessor must be configured with this CRI log format. Example here.

